# Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[tabindex]

Tags: angular

I am getting this strange error from my very basic application currently. I cant get the application to run due to this issue. It seems like some vital bit of information is missing from the exception. Im sure i have all the imports/etc correct

```
core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[tabindex]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[tabindex]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for tabindex!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[tabindex]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[tabindex]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for tabindex!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:1354)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1681)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1607)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1470)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1681)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1607)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1470)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:23104)
    at _createClass (core.js:23181)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:23137)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:30873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

My components:

home.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterLink} from '@angular/router';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {ApiClientService} from '../helpers/api-client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: RouterLink,
              private cookieService: CookieService,
              private apiClient: ApiClientService) {
  }

  topTracks: Observable<string>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    debugger;
    const cookieVal = this.cookieService.get('token');
    if (cookieVal === '') {
      this.apiClient.login().subscribe(token => {
        this.cookieService.set('token', token);
        this.topTracks = this.apiClient.getTopTracks(token);
      });
    } else {
      this.topTracks = this.apiClient.getTopTracks(cookieVal);
    }
  }
}
```

Authentication component:

```
 import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterLink} from '@angular/router';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import {ApiClientService} from '../helpers/api-client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-authentication',
  templateUrl: './authentication.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./authentication.component.css']
})
export class AuthenticationComponent implements OnInit {
  private code: any;

  constructor(private httpClient: ApiClientService,
              private routerLink: ActivatedRoute,
              private cookieService: CookieService,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routerLink.queryParams.subscribe(param => {
      this.code = param['code'];
      this.httpClient.swapCode(this.code).subscribe(retVal => {
        this.cookieService.set('token', retVal);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      });
    });
  }

}
```

and app Module

i

```
mport { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Router, RouterLink, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AuthenticationComponent } from './authentication/authentication.component';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import {ApiClientService} from './helpers/api-client.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AuthenticationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'authenticate/:code', component: AuthenticationComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [RouterLink, CookieService, ApiClientService, HttpClient],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and my api client:

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiClientService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_API_URL') private baseUrl: string) {
  }

  login(): Observable<string> {
    return this.httpClient.get<string>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Authentication/AuthenticateAuth');
  }

  swapCode(code: any) {
    return this.httpClient.get<string>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Authentication/code/' + code);
  }

  getTopTracks(cookieVal: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get<string>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Spotify/Top/' + cookieVal);
  }
}
```